# Problemas con consulta JOIN SQL Server

Tags: sql, join

Tengo dos tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienen el Campo1 y Campo5 en común, entonces he intentado la siguiente consulta:

```
Select Campo1, Campo2, Campo3, Campo4, Campo6
From Tabla1 T1 
Inner join Tabla2 T2 
On (T1.Campo1 = T2.Campo5)
```

esperando tener algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé por qué me da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de agregarme el resultado me lo duplica :/
¿Alguien tiene una idea? Ya he intentado con UNION, Left Join y Right Join. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa que en una de las dos tablas no haya información duplicada. Si es el caso, recuerda poner en los campos "campo1" y "campo5" como llaves primarias poniendo `primary key` en la definición de la columna al momento de crear la tabla.

Algo de la forma.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla1 (
  campo1 varchar(250) not null primary key,
  campo2 varchar(250),
  campo3 varchar(250),
  campo4 varchar(250)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabla2 (
  campo5 varchar(250) not null primary key,
  campo6 varchar(250),
  campo7 varchar(250)
);
```

O puedes borrar los duplicados y, solo después de haberlo hecho, crear llaves primarias sobre esos campos.

```
ALTER TABLE tabla1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (campo1);
ALTER TABLE tabla2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (campo5);
```

Y volver a correr la consulta que tienes.

O (no recomiendo esto), al final de tu consulta, pide que la muestre con un `distinct`.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  campo1,
  campo2,
  campo3,
  campo4,
  campo6
FROM
  tabla1 T1
INNER JOIN
  tabla2 T2
  ON 
    T1.campo1 = T2.campo5
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pues funcionó con el Distinct :/ aunque pues si me gustaría saber por qué es que me está devolviendo los duplicados ya que se supone que el inner join no funciona así, pero bueno, funcionó, gracias jejeje

Comment: Si te funcionó, me harías un favor emocional al votar arriba la pregunta o ponerle como válida. Y trata de no usar el DISTINCT, mejor revisa los datos de tu tabla porque, en un futuro, si continuas con esas prácticas, te puede dar un dolor de cabeza porque habría muchísimos (millones) de registros duplicados que se tendrían que "desduplicar".

Comment: @EriK si te esta retornando datos duplicados entonces conviene mirar su tu estrcutura de BD es la correcta; para empezar cada tabla deberá tener una `PK`